# I2C Shifter being used to protect against short to much higher supply rail

Tags: i2c, circuit-protection, level-shifting

For a device I'm retrofitting, there is a risk that some I2C datalines could be shorted to a supply rail that can be between 12-44V, or ground

To the best of my understanding this bodge circuit per data line should protect against this condition frying the device, as long as I choose a mosfet with a source-drain voltage rating higher than my expected supply rails, but I felt I would feel out the idea here to make sure its actually going to work how I expect,

The diode is just there to protect against a negative bus rail, if I'm building it I figure may aswell cover all possibilities.

[image]

Comment: A 50k pullup to 35V on the I2C bus? That can’t be good.

Comment: the higher voltage is a fault condition, the main thing is that the device survives,

Comment: if you are going to this much trouble, couldn't you protect it with a comparator?

Comment: @abel could you describe how a comparator would work in this context? Its unclear to me what your mean

Comment: If the shorting is a fault condition and you wouldn't mind interrupting the data line, there is always the option of a crowbar circuit and fuse.

Answer (score 0):

Using a comparator to protect a circuit is relatively simple.  An op amp output is limited to its supply terminals' voltages, however it's input terminals can usually accept a higher voltage even under such conditions.  Op amps also tend to be sufficiently fast to copy digital data bus signals.  You will have to look at spec sheets and find one that has the voltage limits and response times you need.

Essentially what would happen is that you limit the op amp's output to 0-3V even if the bus is -44-44 V.  If the comparison point is set to 1.5V, it will produce 3V for the range of 1.5-44V and 0V for -44-1.5V.  That would effectively limit what the sensitive device experiences from the high voltage error condition, although you might get bad digital data injected, the amp would be what bears the high voltage and your I2C device would not get fried.

While the action is somewhat similar to a mosfet, you get both high and low side protections over a known wide range, and the comparison point is adjustable.  Adjustability might just let you eek out good signal under bad conditions with a proper circuit.

"if I'm building it I figure may aswell cover all possibilities"
While covering all possibilities may be in the realm of impossibility, you can look to build for potential adjustments in the future.

You can also use comparators to activate other circuits should the voltage on the bus fall out of range, and protect output lines as well (usually as a buffer), although simple high impedance might be better for output scenarios.